# Find cell at given screen position in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, grid

I'm creating simple game which board is based on Grid layout. I make f.e. 20rows x 20columns grid, some of them are filled by some FrameworkElement. I want to make drag&drop mechanism for them and I wonder how to find row&column of grid by mouse position.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found such function:

```
public Cell GetCell(Point position)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.Column = -1; 
        double total = 0;
        foreach (var column in boardGrid.ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            if(position.X < total)
            {
                break;
            }
            cell.Column++;
            total += column.ActualWidth;
        }

        cell.Row = -1;
        total = 0;
        foreach (var row in boardGrid.RowDefinitions)
        {
            if(position.Y < total)
            {
                break;
            }
            cell.Row++;
            total += row.ActualHeight;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```